# coverage.py: exclude files

Tags: python, testing, software-quality, code-coverage, coverage.py

How do I exclude entire files from [coverage.py](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/) reports?

According to the documentation you can exclude code by matching lines. I want to exclude entire files, so that the reports don't include 3rd party libraries. Am I missing something? Can it be done?

Comment: If nobody else gives you an answer, Ned will probably be around soon to clear things up -- he's a regular around here :)

Comment: I don't know if it's a good thing that I'm so predictable! :)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can omit modules with the --omit flag.  It takes a comma-separated list of path prefixes.  So for example:

```
coverage run my_program.py
coverage report --omit=path/to/3rdparty
```

Comment: In the API, you provide a list of modules you want to report on, so there's not a lot of convenient control there.

Comment: @NedBatchelder  This doesn't work for me, see http://pastebin.com/YFg3fbmW . I have `coverage.py, version 3.5.2.  http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage`. Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @moose I had the same issue. Solved it by using a wildcard. Like so: `coverage report --omit="../../django-tastypie/*"`. Note the `*` at end.

Comment: What if I want to omit multiple files, can I configure it somewhere like `setup.cfg`

Comment: @VaibhavVishal use commas `--omit=dir1/*,dir2/*`

Answer (score 34):

In addition to the options in the other answers, you can also configure the ignored files via `setup.cfg`:

```
[coverage:run]
omit =
    some/directory/*
    debug_*.py
```

See the [documentation](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source.html#execution) for details.

Answer (score 15):

Omitting some files worked for me using coverage API.
Well it is the same kind what Ned suggested.

Here it is how I did it:

`cov = coverage.coverage(omit='/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/*')`

Answer (score 12):

With `pyproject.toml`

```ini
[tool.coverage.run]
omit = [
    "some/directory/*",
    "other/lib.py"
]
```

Answer (score 11):

Create a new file `.coveragerc` and add the following lines

```
[run]
branch = True
omit =
    directory/*
```