# How to update coverage (that is inclued in pybuilder) to igrore run.py module?

Tags: python, flask, code-coverage, pybuilder

**Problem:** Flask app being built with Pybuilder needs Coverage to exclude run.py during the build to get rid of the warn message and impact on coverage percentage

```
[WARN]  Module 'run' was not imported by the covered tests
```

and

```
[WARN]  Test coverage below 70% for run:  0%
```

in

```
(env3)$ python3 build.py
PyBuilder version 0.11.9
Build started at 2017-01-23 12:48:03
------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  Building myproject version 0.0.1.00526
[INFO]  Executing build in /Users/zzzz/Documents/Projects/myproject
[INFO]  Going to execute tasks: clean, install_dependencies, analyze, publish
[INFO]  Removing target directory /Users/zzzz/Documents/Projects/myproject/target
[INFO]  Installing all dependencies
[INFO]  Running unit tests
[INFO]  Executing unit tests from Python modules in /Users/zzzz/Documents/Projects/myproject/src/unittest/python
[INFO]  Executed 14 unit tests
[INFO]  All unit tests passed.
[INFO]  Executing flake8 on project sources.
[INFO]  Collecting coverage information
[WARN]  coverage_branch_threshold_warn is 0 and branch coverage will not be checked
[WARN]  coverage_branch_partial_threshold_warn is 0 and partial branch coverage will not be checked
[INFO]  Running unit tests
[INFO]  Executing unit tests from Python modules in /Users/zzzz/Documents/Projects/myproject/src/unittest/python
[INFO]  Executed 14 unit tests
[INFO]  All unit tests passed.
[WARN]  Module 'run' was not imported by the covered tests
------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILED - Build aborted
------------------------------------------------------------
Build finished at 2017-01-23 12:48:16
Build took 12 seconds (12694 ms)
[WARN]  Test coverage below 70% for run:  0%
[WARN]  Test coverage below 70% for run:  0%
[WARN]  Test coverage below 70% for app.mod_upload: 21%
[WARN]  Test coverage below 70% for app.mod_upload: 21%
[INFO]  Overall coverage is 79%
[INFO]  Overall coverage branch coverage is 66%
[INFO]  Overall coverage partial branch coverage is 77%
[INFO]  Overall coverage is 79%
[INFO]  Overall coverage branch coverage is 66%
[INFO]  Overall coverage partial branch coverage is 77%
(env3)$
```

**Question:** I could have used [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559424/coverage-py-exclude-files) , but coverage executed by pybuild, not by myself from command line, so --omit solution does not quite applicable, which creates the issue. Could someone please advise?

Comment: That warning is from pybuilder ([here](https://github.com/pybuilder/pybuilder/blob/3bb52943e4e78dc316525f6facd2231bc956f5c1/src/main/python/pybuilder/plugins/python/coverage_plugin.py#L165)), so a generic coverage.py answer probably will not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer!
Solution:
in build.py (part of pybuilder project) add:

```
@init
def set_properties(project):
    project.set_property("coverage_exceptions", ['run',])
```

list could be expanded with other modules as needed.

Comment: Thanks for this! You can use wildcard e.g. `"my_excluded_module.*"` as necessary.