Increasing test coverage for files I didn't write
I have written a python program that calculates various statistical values of a given list of integers and the range of values. Now, I am trying to write a test file for the program that can achieve >98% coverage. Currently, It only has 33% coverage. According to my coverage report, all of the files of code that I have written have at least 87% coverage, but there are three files of code that I did not write that are included in the report, and each of them have only between 20-40% coverage:
calculator.py                                                   20   2      0   90%
program.py                                                      17   0      0   100%
results.py                                                      23   3      0   87%
tests/__init__.py                                               0    0      0   100%
tests/test_statistics.py                                        77   1      0   99%
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sortedcontainers/__init__.py     10   0      0   100%
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.py   195  139    0   29%
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.py   1009 763    0   24%
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sortedcontainers/sortedset.py    183  117    0   36%

Total                                                           1534 1025   0   33%

How can I increase my test coverage when I didn't write the code in the bottom 3 modules?

You can omit the files you don't want to consider for coverage: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559424/coverage-py-exclude-files

If you are only interested in your files, you should use --source=. (or the equivalent in your config file).  This will limit the focus to your files, and additionally find your files that were never executed at all.
